# modifying bitcoind to include mysql support

Tags: bitcoind, compiling, make, mysql

I am modifying bitcoind (working with 0.13.1) to include write the log to mysql db versus the log file. 
I have all the functions worked out and compiling outside of bitcoind

The trouble I ran into is when trying to compile it all with bitcoind.
i added my new file (.cpp and .h) into the makefile and linked `-lmysqlclient`, but im getting
`undefined reference to 'mysql_init'`

any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `-lmysqlclient` under `LIBS` in `configure.ac` did the trick
the new line reads as follows:

`LIBS="$LIBS_TEMP  -lmysqlclient"`